# Catch text with regex only if there is dots and commas

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm using this regex to catch numbers and dots and commas: `(?:\s[\d.,]+)`

So, this regex will work for:

```
5
55
5,5
5.5
```

But i need just the numbers with dots and commas, so i don't need 5 or 55 in this case. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following version for multiple dots and commas;

`\d+([,.]\d+)+`

Answer (score 0):

Then slightly change it to:

```
\d+[,.]\d+
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/eG0qX3/1)

Comment: Hm, what about cases with 55,55,55? Or 55.55,55? or 555.55.55.55? I'm sorry for missing that.

Comment: it will partially match... should it or not ? provide conditions then!!